# How to validate router parameter?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

In [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious) I can access parameters as showed in [Example](http://corky.net/dotan/programming/mojolicious-request-parameters-example.html):

```
$c->param( 'login' );
```

Here I do not care about this is router, query or body parameter.

But when I try to validate it, I is unavailable:

```
$c->validation->param( 'login' );
```

May I validate router parameters with [Mojolicious validation](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Validator/Validation)?

Comment: I don't understand how you expect `$self->validation->param( 'login' )` to work. `Mojolicious` objects have no `validation` method. I think the page that you link to is clear about how to use the `Mojolicious::Validator::Validation` class, and it is very hard to offer help without knowing why you have written something completely different from the examples there.

Comment: @Borodin `$self` is controller: http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Controller#validation

Answer (score 1):

It seems will be handy if Mojolicious allow to control that over parameter. So we can supply what we want to check:

```
# default behavior
my $v =  $self->validation;  
# arguments from route
my $v =  $self->validation( 'route' );   
# arguments from route with specified precedence
my $v =  $self->validation( 'request', 'body' );
```